# Possible to skin iPhone main (desktop) interface/background?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch

I know it's possible for jailbroken iPhones but does Apple provide any API for skinning the main mobile desktop interface/background?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apple **does not** provide any API's for skinning the main mobile desktop interface/background.